# Convert a stream of Objects to a Map

Tags: java

I would like to convert a stream of Objects to a Map. The key is the object itself and the value is `Function.identity()`. My goal is to create an incremental index for every Person.

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}

/* Expected Result
  Key:[Person1], value:1  
  Key:[Person2], value:2  
  Key:[Person3], value:3
*/
public Map<Person, Integer> getMapOfPersons(Stream<Person> persons) {
  return persons.filter(p -> "John".equalIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person, Function.identity()));
}
```

My problem is that after applying the `.filter()`, I can't put my object as a key (or even value) in `.toMap()` method.

Comment: what is the identity?

Comment: I want to create a Map with indexes that's why I used Function.identity()

Comment: You want the person objects as values of the map? What should be the keys?

Comment: An incremental number (index): Example (Person1, 1), (Person2, 2), (Person3, 3) etc...

Comment: @Pryda could you please clarify: should the incremental number index be the value or key of the map

Comment: @AlexanderDaum I could use it as a key or a value. It doesn't really matter. Both elements are unique: Person and the incremental number

Comment: @Pryda if it doesn't matter from an application perspective I would use the integer as the key, as it would probably have a faster `hashCode` method and does not depend on a good `hashCode` implementation on in your class. Also It would allow fast index -> Person lookup.
If you want fast index -> Person and Person -> index lookup take a look at the Guava BiMap that can map in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it in two steps:

```
public Map<Person, Integer> getMapOfPersons(Stream<Person> persons) {
  List<Person> filterd = persons.filter(p -> "John".equalIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
  return IntStream.range(0, filterd.size())
                  .boxed()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(filterd::get, i -> i + 1));
}
```

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) says: *"There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`"*. Since the `List<Person>` is not guaranteed to be array-based, calling `get(i)` can be very bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public Map<Person, Integer> getMapOfPersons(Stream<Person> persons) {
  AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
  return persons.filter(p -> "John".equalIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName())
  .collectors.toMap(p->p, counter.getAndIncrement());
}
```

Comment: `p->p` and `Function.identity()` are the same thing. This is creating a map with the same key and value...

Comment: Is there a way I can create a Map from this stream with an index associated to each object?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AtomicInteger` to generate an increasing value as value to your `Map`:

```
public Map<Person, Integer> getMapOfPersons(Stream<Person> persons) {
  final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
  return persons
      .filter(p -> "John".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName()))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), notUsed -> atomicInteger.incrementAndGet()));
}
```

Beware of using this with parallel streams since it relies on the order of the processing. It will, however, render unique values since `AtomicInteger` is thread safe.